# Whether I can pop up a more modal of iView?

Tags: vue.js, iview

I use [iView's Modal](https://www.iviewui.com/components/modal):

I try to popup a more modal in the modal's function:

```
     this.$Modal.confirm({
      render: (h) => {
        return h('Button', {
          props: {
            value: this.value,
            type: 'primary',
          },

          on: {
            click: function (e) {
              // There I want to popup a more Modal，but the `this`is `null` 
              this.$Modal.confirm({
                render: (h) => {
                  return h('Input', {

                  })
                }
              })
            }
          }
        })
      }
    })
```

You see, I use the `render` function to generate the modal content, but the button in it can not invoke my requirement code now, because I can not use the `this` in there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    let self = this;
    this.$Modal.confirm({
    render: (h) => {
    return h('Button', {
      props: {
        value: this.value,
        type: 'primary',
      },
      on: {
        click: function (e) {
          // There I want to popup a more Modal，but the `this`is `null` 
          self.$Modal.confirm({
            render: (h) => {
              return h('Input', {

              })
            }
          })
        }
      }
    })
  }
})
```

Comment: the `self` is undefined, brother.